# Android 2-way sync-ing approach

Tags: android

I'm developing an app which list the shops around my area by category. I have a REST API where the results would be returned in paginated mode (page=2, limit=20 etc) and users will need to login to the app in order to view the listing.

I'm thinking to incorporate offline 2 way sync into my app. The moment when user logs in for the first time he has to be connected to the internet and subsequently once he has logged in he should be able to proceed straight to the main screen eventhough the app is offline.

User also has the ability to post a review offline in which I suppose we should cache the post request in the DB and listen to network state changed event? Once there's a network then query everything in the cache and send to the server.

I understand how this can be achieved at high level but I'm still new to Android and not exposed to the popular libraries out there. Just wondering is there any library that is already doing all the magic for me?

I stumble across Sync Adapter and Content Provider but it seems like they are quite complicated to a beginner. Is there a simpler library that can achieve similar results?

Also from my understanding the way how it works would be.. there will be a service that periodically poll server for changes - and fetch when there's any then store into SQLite. On poll it will also retrieve client changes and send to server. When user views listing the app will retrieve from SQLite instead making request to the server - there is no direct interfacing between the App and server. Can anyone verify if my understanding is correct?